# Issues about using an external USB HDD for multibooting & data storage

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, multi-boot, liveusb

I’d like to use a 5TB external USB HDD for multibooting GParted, Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and Windows 10, while still being able to use it as my data storage drive. I know I could buy a 16GB pendrive for multibooting, but I’d rather having a single unit for it all.

**Is it advisable to do so?**

- *Would this cause risk of losing data?*
- *Would the bootable software work correctly?*

**If the answer to previous questions is “yes”:**

- *How should I dispose partitions on my HDD?*
- *Can I change its partitions without losing current data on it?*

The HDD is a ADATA HD710Pro, and it currentily has a single NTFS partition. I have a
backup of my data (~2.8TB), but it would be quite annoying to copy it
back again, as it is distributed on several other drives.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - you certainly can run Windows on an external USB drive, I run 10 Pro on one and it boots fine. You need not use Windows To Go.

Comment: After re-reading the question, I must admit it wasn't clear, as it is kind of an embedded question. I'll rewrite it soon.

Comment: Many live installers use dd to create bootable flash drive. That totally erases drive, so do not use those. I only use a full install of Ubuntu to flash drives 16GB or over. I just changed my M.2 SATA drive to NVMe and put SATA drive into USB enclose. Fast, especially compared to flash drives. With full install I have grub also loopmount ISO, so have many ISO on larger drives. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c UEFI install to external more complicated.https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379